# Botão "Curtir" Facebook customizado

Tags: facebook, jquery-mobile

Existe alguma maneira de customizar ou construir o botão "***Like/Curtir***" (para uma página) do ***Facebook***?

Gostaria de um customizado, pois o original não se encaixa no *design* do *app mobile* que estou desenvolvendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um plugin chamado [`Fancylike`](https://github.com/openproj/jquery-fancylike) que deve servir para o propósito.

Inclua o plugin:

```js
<script src="jquery.fancylike.js"></script>
```

Criar um *conteiner* para o botão:

```js
<div class="fancylike-fb-like"></div>
```

Chamar o plugin, com a detecção automática da URL a curtir(*ou seja url atual*):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".fancylike-fb-like").fancylike();
});
</script>
```